# LM1117 3.3 output gives 4.2

Tags: voltage-regulator, 3.3v

I used this  circuit and formula as a reference for 5V to 3.3V

[image: this]

It's from the LM1117 datasheet but output gives 4.2V.  Here  is my circuit:

[image: this]

I changed resistors with different values but output give same 4.2V. What can be the problem or how can I find my fault.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98030/discussion-on-question-by-7navy4-lm1117-3-3-output-gives-4-2).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE, because the answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.

Comment: A photo of your physical circuit might help us spot a problem.

Comment: For anyone thinking that the cause is D6 being fitted in a reverse direction: One of the comments [moved to chat above](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98030/discussion-on-question-by-7navy4-lm1117-3-3-output-gives-4-2) was [this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51519690#51519690), which states that the same problem remains even after D6 has been totally removed. Therefore a reverse-fitted D6 is not the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you building your circuit on a solderless breadboard? If so, it's very easy to miswire your feedback resistors and see strange problems like this one. I've seen similar problems before.

Also, I see you have a decoupling capacitor at Vadj, the junctions between resistors and capacitors can be pretty confusing on a breadboard, and can be easily miswired. I suggest you to remove the capacitor at `Vadj` pin, leaving two resistors and one output capacitor only. First, make sure the resistor network is correctly connected. Add the Vadj capacitor later, only after you see the correct output voltage.

I managed to reproduce your problem, it's only one possible way for things to go wrong, but as an example, consider this simple LM1117 circuit.

[image: LM1117 example]

According to the formula, it should output

$$ V_{out} = 1.25 \times (1 + \frac{220}{100}) = 4.0 $$

Now let's build the circuit on the breadboard...

[image: Wrong breadboard example]

And the moment of truth, let's measure the output voltage.

[image: Voltmeter shows 4.192 volt]

4.2 volt?!

Can you find the mistake? In this case, the problem is caused by the miswired yellow wires. Just a few more additional wires, like adding a capacitor at Vadj, on the breadboard can make it difficult to notice.

[image: Miswired portion of the breadboard.]

The right side of the resistor network should be connected to Pin 2 of the LM1117, the center-tap should be connected to Pin 1. But in this diagram, it's connected backwards, so the Vadj won't receive the proper feedback, and R2 would get extremely hot soon as Vout is connected to ground via R2.

What is the moral of the story?

1. The human brain is not a good netlist processor. If you want to make sure your wiring is correct, you may still want to use a PCB layout tool. You can draw a breadboard-like grid and route inside first, and transfer it to the physical breadboard. The computer can help you ensure the layout is correct.
2. Often, you can have better results by not using a solderless breadboard at all, as Lundin commented. For example, a breadboard forces you to route your circuit horizontally, many mistakes can be avoided on a perfboard as you can route to all directions, and there won't be any accidental open or short circuit due to loose springs or touched metal wires underneath.
3. It's only one possible way for things to go wrong. You must post a high-resolution picture that clearly shows the construction and connections for us to help.

Comment: Where did you get that formula? Shouldn't it rather just be 1.25V/3.3V = R1/(R1+R2).

Comment: (Btw breadboards are horrible. A cheap soldier iron costs about the same, but gives far better reliability. I tossed all breadboards in the garbage long time ago, never missed them.)

Comment: @Lundin Oops, I kept thinking about 3.3v... fixed.

Comment: @比尔盖子 Thank you so much for your answer. I'm sorry for late response. I did everything also i have 3 LM1117 and i tried three of them but i couldn't fix it. Then i buy different  voltage regulator LM317 then it work.

Comment: @7navy4 No worries. A defective part is always a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't tell more about the circuit . That must be a noise problem mostly could  be a ripple problem you have to stop ripples from being amplified by choosing the right capacitor values .

> 8.2.2.1.2 Adjust Terminal Bypass Capacitor
>       The adjust terminal can be bypassed to ground with a bypass capacitor (CADJ) to improve ripple rejection. This
>       bypass capacitor prevents ripple from being amplified as the output voltage is increased. At any ripple frequency,
>       the impedance of the CADJ should be less than R1 to prevent the ripple from being amplified:
>       1/(2π × fRIPPLE × CADJ) < R1 (1)
>       The R1 is the resistor between the output and the adjust pin. Its value is normally in the range of 100-200Ω. For
>       example, with R1 = 124Ω and fRIPPLE = 120Hz, the CADJ should be > 11µF.

source : [Data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf)

You could watch video about how ripples can affect the output [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wopmEyZKnYo)

Comment: thank you so much. I couldn't fix the problem then change voltage regulator and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

The 120 and 200 ohm resistor values calculate an output voltage of 3.33V, not 4.2V.

Maybe you are using a defective or fake IC from ebay?.