# DAC7760 voltage and current output

Tags: dac, 4-20ma

I use the following function to send data from STM32f1 to a DAC7760:

```
static HAL_StatusTypeDef WriteSingle_DAC7760(uint8_t ch_Addr, uint16_t ch_Data){     
  uint8_t liv_Data[3]; // 0: ch_Addr  1:ch_Datadata?8? 2:ch_Datadata?8?
  uint8_t liv_RXData[3] = {0};
  liv_Data[0] = ch_Addr;
  liv_Data[1] = (ch_Data & 0xff00) >> 8;
  liv_Data[2] = ch_Data & 0x00ff;
  status = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi2, liv_Data, liv_RXData, 3, 500); 
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_Delay(1);
  return status;
}
```

According to these tables from datasheet 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4xCj.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W23P8.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIrBi.jpg

I use this initial settings for DAC7760

```
//Write reset register
WriteSingle_DAC7760(0x56, 0x0001);

//Write control register 1001 0000 0000 0001  
WriteSingle_DAC7760(0x55, 0x9001);

//configuration register 0000 0011 0000 0000
WriteSingle_DAC7760(0x57,0x0300);
```

and this is the last line for taking voltage and current output from DAC

```
WriteSingle_DAC7760(0x01,32000);
```

But there is no output on 4-20 mA current output and voltage output. Am I missing a part or did I do something wrong?

here spi configurations

```
hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
  hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi2.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_32;
  hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
```

Comment: Hi, (a) Have you got a logic analyser or oscilloscope, to check that the SPI bus is showing the correct data transfer? (b) None of the answers on your previous questions have been accepted. And you seem to have abandoned (at least, not replied to) [a recent question which got a lot of attention](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/455168/lm1117-3-3-output-gives-4-2), where [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/455779) took a long time to write for you. That might affect how much effort readers give your future questions. Can you respond to answers received? Thanks!

Comment: @SamGibson hi, a) No i haven't oscilloscope, i tried to read registers but i couldn't read. probably the problem is spı. I add spi configurations. b) I'm sorry for that i answer as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, (a) For this type of problem, I would not troubleshoot only by looking at the code, but also look at the actual SPI signals. That way you can quickly see whether your problem is (i) SPI signals not as expected = SPI initialisation or MCU config problem; or (ii) SPI signals as expected, but wrong response from DAC = DAC programming is wrong (or DAC faulty). Although oscilloscopes can show waveform details that are invisible with a logic analyser, it is possible to get much cheaper logic analysers these days. I suggest you start with a cheap 24MHz USB analysers and sigrok s/w. Good luck!

Comment: @SamGibson i found a logic analyser and when power supply turned off spi seen work well but when i turned on power supply for dac with 24V mosi output corrupt and sen just one pulse while clock data send clock pulses. i looked mosi trace but there is no problem with mosi pin trace.

Comment: Thanks for the new info. Some details were not clear to me, but it seems switching the 24V supply to the DAC (I guess you mean its AVDD supply) affects the SPI signals. This is a good example of why I didn't assume that this problem could be solved by the code you supplied. Since your new info suggests that h/w is involved, you need to update the question to add *all* the details of your design, including schematic, photos of the h/w you are using, analyser traces, and details of the history e.g. any previous prototypes which worked? Why do you believe it is OK to turn on/off AVDD to the DAC?

Comment: @SamGibson i was using spi2 and i changed to spi1 and it was fixed mosi start to send right data while adc supplied with 24V but still DAC not give any output and i control DAC pins and ALARM pin is low state. but it have to be high state for dac work. Can dac be corrupted or are the any other thing that i miss.

Comment: Sorry, but in my experience, we're unlikely to solve this until you supply **full** details of your design, and all of the info I listed before (that's a minimum - more info might be requested later). You must also add a chronological list of each change you have done and the result of that change. I know this would all take you a long time :-( You must decide if you want to continue. Also, I guess your first language isn't English, and unfortunately some parts of your comments so far are too unclear for me to understand :-( Perhaps you should ask for help from someone local to you? Good luck!

Comment: @SamGibson Thank you for your response.  I use schematic from datasheet so i don't think it's about design. Last situation is spi send correct data but DAC not receive these data because of ALARM pin give 0V output so DAC not work. Sorry for my english.